# Problem in upgrading OpenCart from version 3.0.3.2 to 3.0.3.6

Tags: opencart, opencart-3

Got modules disabled in Modification manager in opencart.

I have upgrade the my opencart website version from 3.0.3.2 to 3.0.3.6, after clicking the refresh button in Extension > Modification, my website stop working.

**Version 3.0.3.2**

[image: Version 3.0.3.2]

**After upgrading the version 3.0.3.6**

[image: After upgrading the version 3.0.3.6]

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Have you tried with default theme? Maybe this is the SO theme issue

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, that your theme **SO Marker** uses good old VQMOD. In that case you should clear VQMOD cache first.

Go to *vqmod/vqcache* folder via FTP and delete all files in it.

Then go to *vqmod* folder and remove file `mods.cache`

After that you can update OCMOD/system/twig cache in admin panel.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I did not found vqmod folder in my opecart system.